# VS 2013: Server Tag not well formed

Tags: javascript

```
    function changeSystemDDLIndex() {
        // Select the Site in SitesDDL = CustomerSiteIdOfSystem
        // Save the System ID into a hidden variable
        var systemsDDL = document.getElementById('ddlSystems');
        var system = systemsDDL.options[systemsDDL.selectedIndex].value;
        var sitesDDL = document.getElementById('ddlSites');
        var hidCustomerSiteId = document.getElementById("hdnCustomerSiteId");
        var hidCustomerSystemId = document.getElementById("hdnCustomerSystemId");

        if (systemsDDL.options[systemsDDL.selectedIndex].value == '') {
            // if System = N/A, Customer_Site_Id = '' then SitesDDL.SelectedIndex = 0 (N/A)
            sitesDDL.options[0].selected = true;

            // Set new values of hidden variables
            hidCustomerSiteId.value = '';
            hidCustomerSystemId.value = '';
        }
        else {
            var isFound = false;
            var CustomerSiteIdOfSystem = systemsDDL.options[systemsDDL.selectedIndex].attributes['Customer_Site_Id'].value;

            // Find the Customer_Site_Id in SitesDDL options and set it
            var j = sitesDDL.options.length;
            var i;

            alert('i = ' + i);
            alert('j = ' + j);
            i++;
            alert('j = ' + j);
            alert('i = ' + i);
            **for (i = 1; i < j; i++) {**
                alert('dfd');
            }

        }
        return;
    }
```

I receive "The server tag is not well formed." error at "for (i = 1; i < j; i++) {" statement. If I remove the for statement, the code works.

How can I correct it please? I am using VS2013, .Net FW 3.5.

Comment: `console.log()` is a much more effective and less invasive means of debugging than using `alert()`.

Comment: Why this code isn't working like questions are off topic in SO

Comment: @SagarV no. such questions are only off-topic if the question doesn't contain enough information to answer the question.  In this case OP has made a good effort in providing us with enough code.  It would be better to ask him for additional information that's missing before voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @Amy Ok I have retracted my CV.